# Anaconda installation in raspberry pi

Tags: operating-system, anaconda, raspberry-pi3

Not running from 32 bit and 64 bit too. I have installed both setup 10 times but it is not working.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi has an ARM CPU and not an x86 CPU. Try this one out:
https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-3.16.0-Linux-armv7l.sh